What are the best packages/commands for maintaining quality in resized images?
I was asked to provide higher resolution versions of my Mathematica figures for a journal publication, and when I looked at the output produced with the publisher's template, the readability of some of the smaller lettering was not perfect.  The axis labels were very slightly fuzzy.
However, I wanted to avoid remaking all my figures at a higher resolution if possible.  Just fooling around, I tried doubling the dimensions of a PNG image (just using the Windows Paint accessory), then using the same LaTeX code to insert it into a manuscript.  I wasn't expecting that to make any difference (since there was no additional information beyond that in the original PNG files), but it actually did!  The revised PDF was definitely less blurry than the original, which suggests that the resizing in the \includegraphics command was not doing the optimal job of preserving resolution/readability when changing the size.  The two-step process of

expansion of the image in Paint
reduction of the image in \includegraphics in pdfLaTeX

produced superior results to using the second step only.  Moreover, I tried using five different applications (both Web based and local) to view both PDF files, and the effect was present in every case; so it does not appear to be a reader artifact.
Here is the code I was using:
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=0,width=14cm]{Absvalue_g_0.10.png}
\caption{The upper (left) and lower (right) components of the time-evolving Dirac wave function,
plotted in terms of position $x$ and time $t$ for the coupling value $g=0.10$, domain wall oscillation
amplitude $v=10$, and frequency $\omega=0.50$.
The starting $\psi$ is a symmetric bound state of the instantaneous
$V(x,t=0)$.}
\label{fig-abs0.10}
\end{figure}

Is there a better way of including PNG graphics, which does not have this resolution problem?  It seems like a properly coded graphics insertion command ought to be able to resize an image as well as the two-step process I ended up using.

What kind of images are these? Fotos? Scientific curves, flow charts etc.? How did you create it, i.e. which program did you use if it's not a foto?

As your image seems to be a time series, investigate the programs "save as .pdf" feature. IF it saves just a bitmap, you're "lost", i.e. have to care for an acceptable resolution, contrast etc. beforehand. IF it saves .pdf as vector graphics, you're lucky: Just follow this approach https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730821/245790 .

latex does nothing at all here, it depends on the engine used and the pdf viewer you used. Obviously if you can generate your plot as a vector format rather than a bitmap you are in a much better position.

@MS-SPO They are plots produced by Mathematica.  I could have reproduced the figures at better resolution in any number of ways, but the point was that the pdfLaTeX engine, via \includegraphics, was doing a manifestly inferior job of preserving the raster graphics information that was contained in the PNG files.

What matters concerning a PNG or JPG is only  (1)  the final width/height of the image  (2) the originals number of pixels. Latex only can change  (1). If you have a poor resolution (said 150 dots per inch), the only thing you can do in latex is reduce the image to half its size or more to have decent resolutions (>300 dpi).  And (2) cannot be changed really.  You can increase the number of pixels and use some interpolation method only to make it smoother, so that it can look better at bigger sizes, but not with more details, but the opposite. Conclusion: use vectorial images if possible.

@Fran You would think that, and I thought that would be the case also.  However, contrary to the apparently logic of the situation, it is simply not true.

your description appears self-contradictory, intially you say the 2 step process of scaling up in paint makes it "less blurry" but then you say the 2 step process "produced inferior results"  but either way it's not really a tex issue,. if you edit the bitmap in paint the file is essentially a different bitmap, if you scale the two bitmaps one or the other may look better depending on many factors, mostly the viewer you use, it is the viewer doing the scaling not tex.

Mathematica can‘t save pdf in vector format??

@DavidCarlisle Sorry, that was a mistake on my part.

@MS-SPO It can, but that's not what I'm asking about.

but that is the answer to the underlying question. If you generate the plot as a bitmap it will always look bad in some cases, so if scaling it up and down makes it look a bit better or a bit worse it isn't really surprising either way, you should simply avoid the problem and use a vector format if possible

@Buzz Using a pdf will most likely also reduce the file size and make the text in your image available for search and screen readers ... many advantages in switching to a vector graphic

"It can, but that's not what I'm asking about." Too bad, it would free you from resolution and blurry problems, as shown in my link. Bye

@Buzz It's not just what I think; it's what I know. I often increase pixels in images using algorithms like bicubic interpolation because it looks better to the human eye, but it doesn't add details. A pixelated face that looks like a Lego figure will appear smoother, more recognizable like a human face, but no new details will really emerge. If you can't recognize who is the person in the original, this won't change no matter the how you increase the pixels even with the best algorithms —only in bad spy movies does that happen.

@Fran There are assumptions about how the resizing algorithms are functioning behind what you say.  They seem to be entirely reasonable assumptions; I shared them until I encountered this.  But they are wrong.

@Buzz It's nonsense to argue when it's easy to check: (1) Capture some text in PNG, reduce the image size until the characters are not legible and are just pixelated blobs. (2) Now do exactly the opposite and you can also apply all the filters you want. Do you get the original sharp letters or just bigger blobs?

well, if you just want to double the number of pixels, just run your images through a conversion programme e.g. assuming paint doesn't do command line, use magick or something. you won't add any information. your images will still look bad in some viewers/applications at some resolutions etc. and they will still be meaningless to people using screen readers. but the process may be slightly more convenient. but I wonder how many you could have recreated as vectors in the time you've spent testing five viewers and refusing to accept what people are telling you.

@Fran The fact that I already did something quite close to that and did not get the expected result was what prompted me to ask this question in the first place.

(la)tex is doing nothing here: exactly the same png data is repackaged as a pdf bitmap stream whatever width you specify. So changing packages will make no difference.
All that happens is the image is surrounded by pdf literals to scale the region, so any scaling/resampling of the bitmap to show at the requested size happens within your pdf reader.
